# New column based on existing string column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, string, numpy, data-wrangling

My dataframe looks like:

| School | Term | Students |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | summer 2020 | 324 |
| B | spring 21 | 101 |
| A | summer/spring | 201 |
| F | wintersem | 44 |
| C | fall trimester | 98 |
| E |  | 23 |

I need to add a new column Termcode that assumes any of the 6 values:
summer, spring, fall, winter, multiple, none based on corresponding value in the Term Column, viz:

| School | Term | Students | Termcode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | summer 2020 | 324 | summer |
| B | spring 21 | 101 | spring |
| A | summer/spring | 201 | multiple |
| F | wintersem | 44 | winter |
| C | fall trimester | 98 | fall |
| E |  | 23 | none |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and filling of the values depending on the number of matches:

```
terms = ['summer', 'spring', 'fall', 'winter']
regex = r'('+'|'.join(terms)+r')'
# '(summer|spring|fall|winter)'

# extract values and set up grouper for next step
g = df['Term'].str.extractall(regex)[0].groupby(level=0)

# get the first match, replace with "multiple" if more than one
df['Termcode'] = g.first().mask(g.nunique().gt(1), 'multiple')

# fill the missing data (i.e. no match) with "none"
df['Termcode'] = df['Termcode'].fillna('none')
```

output:

```
  School            Term  Students  Termcode
0      A     summer 2020       324    summer
1      B       spring 21       101    spring
2      A   summer/spring       201  multiple
3      F       wintersem        44    winter
4      C  fall trimester        98      fall
5      E             NaN        23      none
```

Comment: Worked like clockwork, thanks! I Would you suggest any modification to account for another no match possibility where Term value is something  like say, "full year 21' ( i.e., no match for the one or more of the 4 terms , but not a missing value either) . The Termcode output should still be none, like in the case of missing values.

Comment: I would probably add `full year` or `year` in the list of terms and handle it separately? depends on what you want exactly

Comment: School/Term /Students  as F /full year2021/ 40  should be converted to School/Term /Students/Termcode  as F /full year201/ 40 /none

Comment: Then I believe it should already work

Comment: Indeed it does! Thanks you again.

Answer (score 1):

### `Series.findall`

```
l = ['summer', 'spring', 'fall', 'winter']

s = df['Term'].str.findall(fr"{'|'.join(l)}")
df['Termcode'] = np.where(s.str.len() > 1, 'multiple', s.str[0])
```

---

```
  School            Term  Students  Termcode
0      A     summer 2020       324    summer
1      B       spring 21       101    spring
2      A   summer/spring       201  multiple
3      F       wintersem        44    winter
4      C  fall trimester        98      fall
5      E             NaN        23       NaN
```

Comment: I had a similar approach in mind initially, unfortunately this would count as "multiple" those where there are more that one identical match (e.g., "fall/fall trimester"). This might be unlikely but better be aware of it ;)